# My jquery snippet only works in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website here http://galnova.com

Here is the markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="2015/css/g15.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="index">
<div class="header">
    <ng-include src="'_master_includes/header.html'"></ng-include>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid nill">
    <div class="bg_bottom_stretch">
        <div class="bg_top_center">
            <div class="evertin">
                <div class="caste">
                    <!-- Caste -->
                    <ng-include src="'_master_includes/caste.html'"></ng-include>
                </div>
                <div class="in_content">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <ng-include src="'_master_includes/in_content.html'"></ng-include>
                </div>
                <div class="sub_footer">
                    <!-- Sub Footer -->
                    <ng-include src="'_master_includes/sub_footer.html'"></ng-include>
                </div>
                <div class="toop4"><span>Social Media</span></div>
                <footer>
                    <!-- Footer -->
                    <ng-include src="'_master_includes/footer.html'"></ng-include>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="2015/js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="2015/js/g15.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
var accessToken = '271323200.1677ed0.67c49d5002704bc09c3c77320ec138a2'; // use your own token
// var date = new Date(parseInt(data.data[i].created_time) * 1000);

  $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
    $.each(insta.data,function (photos,src) {
      if ( photos === 200 ) { return false; }
        var date = new Date(parseInt(this.created_time) * 1000);
        // template
        $(
        '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 grip_wrap">' +
        '<div class="grip_hang_topp"></div>' +
        '<div class="col grip">' +

        '<img class="pp" title="" src="' + this.user.profile_picture + '" />' +
        '<div class="coat">' + this.user.username + '</div>' +

        '<a title="' + this.caption.text + '" class="fancybox zero" rel="gallery1" href="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '">' +
        '<img src="' + this.images.thumbnail.url + '" />' +
        '</a>' +
        '<div class="col coat2 truncate">' + this.caption.text + '</div>' +
        '<div class="row nill">' +
        '<span class="col-sm-6 heart-wrap floated">' + '<i class="fa fa-heart">'+ '</i>' + this.likes.count +' <div class="summ">likes</div>'+'</span>' +
        '<span class="col-sm-6 comment-wrap floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-comment">'+ '</i>' + this.comments.count +' <div class="summ">comments</div>'+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<span class="col check-wrap floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-check">'+ '</i>' + 'Posted ' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2) +'</span>' +
        '<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank"><button class="col-12 btn btn-primary">View in Instagram</button></a>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div class="grip_hang_bott"></div>' +
        '</div>'

      ).appendTo('#instafeed');
    }); 
  });
});

$('.grip').hover(function(e){
    $(this).find('.fa-heart, .fa-comment, .fa-check, .btn, img').toggleClass('pls');
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
<a href="#" class="scrollup"></a>
</html>
```

I can't get the jquery snippet I wrote to work on the html page

Here is the snippet

```
$('.grip').hover(function(e){
//  "use strict";
//  e.preventDefault();
//  if ($(window).width() > 991) {
//alert('TEST!!!');
        $(this).find('.fa-heart, .fa-comment, .fa-check, .btn, img').toggleClass('pls');

        return false;
//  }
});
```

I also can't get the jquery to work anywhere in my js file

Here is the js file http://galnova.com/2015/js/g15.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Page Loads/*
"use strict";

    $(document).on('click', '.toggleAll', function(){
        $('.pp, .coat, .heart-wrap, .comment-wrap, .check-wrap, .grip .btn').slideToggle('fast');
        var el = $(this);
        el.text() === el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 52) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});

(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations(elems) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
    $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');

    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });

})(jQuery);

$(document).on('click','.toop',function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#m1').slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).on('click','.toop2',function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#m2').slideToggle('fast');
});

//Resume Slider
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','[id^=claps]',function () {
    "use strict";

    var idNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("claps", "");
    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
        $('.inco'+idNumber).stop().animate({width: 'toggle', height: '125px'});
    }
});

$(document).on('click','#menulink',function (event) {
    "use strict";
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.navigation-wrapper').hasClass('show-menu')) {
        $('.navigation-wrapper').removeClass('show-menu');
        $('.navigation').hide();
        $('.navigation li').removeClass('small-padding');
    } else {
        $('.navigation-wrapper').addClass('show-menu');
        $('.navigation').fadeIn();
        $('.navigation li').addClass('small-padding');
    }
});

//////////////////////////

//This controls the music playback on the media page

window.addEventListener("play", function(evt)
{   "use strict";
    if(window.$_currentlyPlaying)
    {
        window.$_currentlyPlaying.pause();
    } 
    window.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target;
}, true);

$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Please help me understand why the snippet doesn't work on the page and only in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating your .grip elements inside a document ready event handler, on the return of a JSON asynchronous request

```
$(function () {
      $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
          // Your code creating .grip elements
      }
});
```

but you are adding your hover event handlers at the end of the page, outside the document ready event handler and outside the JSON asynchronous request return, your .grip elements don't exist at the moment of adding the hover event handlers (but when you are executing the code in the console, the elements are already existing).

Solution 1:

You can move your code adding the hover event handlers after the creation of you .grip elements, in the JSON request return.

```
$(function () {
      $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
          $.each(insta.data,function (photos,src) {
              // Your code creating .grip elements
          }

          $('.grip').hover(function(e){
              $(this).find('.fa-heart, .fa-comment, .fa-check, .btn, img').toggleClass('pls');
              return false;
          });
      }
});
```

Solution 2:

You can change your jQuery hover event handler binding to use the event delegation feature. http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('#instafeed').on('mouseover', '.grip', function(e){
    $(this).find('.fa-heart, .fa-comment, .fa-check, .btn, img').toggleClass('pls');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Oh wow! The first one worked! Please help me understand why that function wasn't working on it's own and only in the console?

Comment: Sorry I read backwards and it makes sense now. This is all awesome and helpful thanks!